# Need sfwidgetformtextarea syntax

Tags: symfony1

I want to write the following HTML in symfony forms.

```
<textarea name="styled-textarea" onfocus="this.value=''; setbg('#e5fff3');" onblur="setbg('white')">Enter your comment here...</textarea>
```

Please show me the exact sfwidgetformtextarea syntax for the above HTML textarea. Thanks in advance

Comment: You should be using css (`:focus`) to change the colour, and some discrete JS to modify the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create new Class extending a symfony class for forms.

`class YourForm extends sfBaseForm{`

```
`public function setup(
    'your_field_name' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(),array('name'=>"styled-textarea",'onfocus'=>"this.value='';setbg('#e5fff3');",onblur=>"setbg('white')",'value'=>"Enter your comment here......"))
  );`
```

Then just make instances of your class in the your views, good luck

Comment: Hi.Thanks for reply.I want to create a form with text area.I am unable to use the above syntax in forms. Its giving error. It seems that the symfony forms have some specific syntaxes.

Comment: Thanks You very much. I edited your answer since some little syntax errors are there.